# What is the first parameter of standard ClassLoader class constructor for?

Tags: java, classloader

The title says it all, here's the code:

```
private ClassLoader(Void unused, ClassLoader parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    if (ParallelLoaders.isRegistered(this.getClass())) {
        parallelLockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        package2certs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        domains =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<ProtectionDomain>());
        assertionLock = new Object();
    } else {
        // no finer-grained lock; lock on the classloader instance
        parallelLockMap = null;
        package2certs = new Hashtable<>();
        domains = new HashSet<>();
        assertionLock = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you also check [how this `private` constructor is invoked](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#ClassLoader.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)? Because it's documented there

Comment: @UnholySheep so why not just call this method in an initializer block then? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a clever trick to call the security check before the class loader can be instantiated.

A quick experiment confirms the static method is called before any initializers:

```
public class InitializerTest {
    {
        System.out.println("Initializer block");
    }

    private InitializerTest(Void v) {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    protected InitializerTest() {
        this(staticMethod());
    }

    private static Void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Static method");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Static method
Initializer block
Constructor
```

Clearly it will be more secure to never allow a rogue `ClassLoader` subclass to be instantiated than fail it after instantiation.  E.g. even if the superclass failed in its first initializer block, the instance is out there - perhaps an exploit in the `finalize()` method on the subclass would be possible?